# Camera view for a Controller Tabbed bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I declared this in my header:

```objc
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NFNoteCamera : UIImagePickerController

@end
```

and receive 27 semantic issues such as

> Property 'cameraCaptureMode' requires method 'cameraCaptureMode' to be defined - use                    @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

including 'allowsImageEditing', 'allowsEditing' and other camera featured issues. If i had to guess it was something i haven't imported yet.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) says

> **Important** The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode
>   only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support
>   subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not
>   be modified, with one exception. In iOS 3.1 and later, you can assign
>   a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to
>   present additional information or manage the interactions between the
>   camera interface and your code

why dont you just implement its delegate?

```
@interface NFNoteCamera : ParentClass <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
   UIImagePickerController *yourPicker;  
}
@end

@implementation NFNoteCamera
-(void)anyMethod{
yourPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
yourPicker.delegate = self;
[yourPicker setAllowsEditing:BOOL];
              //or photo library(UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)
yourPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:yourPicker animated:YES];
}
//delegate methods
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
       UIImage *producedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
@end
```

Comment: Works great. Wanted to go back and give you credit for this!